# Add common properties of the child objects and append it with Parent Key (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I want to add the common property i.e, total_quantity_sold of the same key and append it with the parent index as total.

This is my products array that I have

```
{ '900001':
   [ anonymous {
       id: '900001',
       name: 'Pack1',
       product: 2017-11-02T13:49:25.596Z,
       total_quantity_sold: '1' },
     anonymous {
       id: '900001',
       name: 'Pack1',
       product: 2018-02-11T13:49:25.596Z,
       total_quantity_sold: '4' },
     anonymous {
       id: '900001',
       name: 'Pack1',
       product: 2017-12-02T13:49:25.596Z,
       total_quantity_sold: '1' } ],
  '900002':
   [ anonymous {
       id: '900002',
       name: 'Pack2',
       product: 2018-01-02T13:49:25.596Z,
       total_quantity_sold: '1' },
     anonymous {
       id: '900002',
       name: 'Pack2',
       product: 2017-11-02T13:49:25.596Z,
       total_quantity_sold: '1' },
     anonymous {
       id: '900002',
       name: 'Pack2',
       product: 2018-02-11T13:49:25.596Z,
       total_quantity_sold: '4' } ],}
```

I want to sum all quantities and append it with the parent key so that my final array looks like this.Actually I want the total count as well as the count by each date is required for graphs to be populated.

```
 { '900001':
       'total' : 6
       [ {
           name: 'Pack1',
           product: 2017-11-02T13:49:25.596Z,
           total_quantity_sold: '1' },
          {
           name: 'Pack1',
           product: 2018-02-11T13:49:25.596Z,
           total_quantity_sold: '4' },
         {

           name: 'Pack1',
           product: 2017-12-02T13:49:25.596Z,
           total_quantity_sold: '1' } ],
      '900002':
       'total' : 7
       [ {

           name: 'Pack2',
           product: 2018-01-02T13:49:25.596Z,
           total_quantity_sold: '2' },
          {

           name: 'Pack2',
           product: 2017-11-02T13:49:25.596Z,
           total_quantity_sold: '1' },
        {

           name: 'Pack2',
           product: 2018-02-11T13:49:25.596Z,
           total_quantity_sold: '4' } ],}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing! You can do it by passing through each entry in the hashtable, and replace it with the target object that you'd like ***in-place***. We can also use a simple reducer to get the total sum of *`quantities sold`*!

### ES7 Way

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach(a => {
  const [key, children] = a
  const total = children.reduce((p,c) => p+c.total_quantity_sold, 0)
  obj[key] = {total, children}
})
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks alot!